# How to start express server in Heroku multi buildpack php + nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, heroku, socket.io, buildpack

I am creating a webapp on Heroku where I need to some realtime data updates in a part of my php application.

So I am thinking I can use socket.io on express server to provide realtime communication functionality.

How should I run the express when its a php buildpack.

Here is my package.json script section

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config config/config.dev.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/config.prod.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

My procfile is...

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

and my buildpacks

```
$ heroku buildpacks
1. heroku/nodejs
2. heroku/php
```

When I deploy this on heroku, I get no compile error in heroku logs but my webapp gets no realtime updates from socket.io server.
In the console log of browser I get a 404 error on http://myapp.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling

What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: How is your "npm start" script triggered, given that your web dyno runs a php process?

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch I have just started using Heroku but I suppose having a nodejs buildpack does not automatically run the start script. What else should I do over here. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: You would need "web: npm start" in your procfile if you want to run a node/express web dyno. However it sounds like you want a PHP web server, with node/express listening on a different port. You can't really do that in Heroku. Instead, you would need a worker dyno for your node app. You would not be able to directly access your worker dyno from your forntend via a URL, though.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch Oh okay. that is very helpful. I have searched a bit about adding worker dyno and using it. I am guessing that I will need to use a communication middleware like redis for the part you mentioned about not being able to directly access worker dyno from frontend.

Comment: Yes, exactly. As described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch awesome. I can build upon this direction of thought. Thanks a lot. Can you post your previous comment as answer so that I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need `web: npm start` in your procfile if you want to run a node/express web dyno.

However it sounds like you want a PHP web server, with node/express listening on a different port. You can't really do that on Heroku. Instead, you would need a worker dyno for your node app. You would not be able to directly access your worker dyno from your frontend via a URL, though. Instead, you would need to do something like what is described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015839/how-to-use-heroku-worker-process-as-api-server/50018639#50018639).